# Why does the `push` method work on the object, in this circumstance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I was under the impression that the method `push` works for arrays, not objects... But then why does the following snippet work?

```
this.usersByMovie = {};

profiles.forEach(profile => {
  const movieID = profile.favoriteMovieID;

  if (this.usersByMovie[movieID]) {

    // the object property is just being accessed using the square brackets
    // so `this.usersByMovie` is still an object, not an array
    // but why is the `push` method working on this object?
    this.usersByMovie[movieID].push(profile.userID);
  } 
  else {
    this.usersByMovie[movieID] = [profile.userID];
  }
});
```

Comment: You're pushing into `this.usersByMovie[movieID]` (which is an array), not into `this.usersByMovie`

Comment: `usersByMovie` is an object of type `{ "movieId1": [] }`

Comment: So, `usersByMovie` was simply created as an object, without any  arrays. But, I assume the array was created when pushing the first element. Is that correct?

Comment: @Grateful `.push()` does not create the array, the creation of the array being done in your `else`: `this.usersByMovie[movieID] = [profile.userID];`, .push only appends an element to an existing array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.usersByMovie[id]` is actually an array, while `this.usersByMovie` is an object.

```
this.usersByMovie[movieID] = [profile.userID];
```

This line of codes makes `this.usersByMovie[id]` as an array.

Comment: There was no array, but when you `push` for the first time, it means that an array's already created in `else`. So, you call `push` from the second element of the array.